# How many five-digit numbers have no $7$s and at least one $3$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many five-digit numbers have no $7$s and at least one $3$?

so $8$ digits max can be used?? - for each placer... $9^5$ would be max range? I'm not good at this

Comment: Show your work please

Comment: so 8 digits max can be used?? - for each placer... 9^5 would be max range? I'm not good at this

Comment: The idea here is to subtract the number of five-digit numbers with no $7$s and no $3$s from the number of five-digit numbers with no $7$s.  Keep in mind that the leading digit cannot be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 digits numbers are ones that are greater than 9999, so $00134$ is not a 5 digit number.

Taking all the 5 digit numbers without the digit 7, will be to have 8 options for the first digit (not 0 and not 7) and 4 times 9 options (not 7), so $n = 8 \cdot 9^4=52488$.

Now, we wish to subtract from that all the 5 digits without 7 and without 3, that will be $k = 7 \cdot  8 ^4=28672$

The result is $52488 - 28672= 23816$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Shahid you are welcome. Upvote and accept as an answer is conventional for an answer that satisfy you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I tried to do that but don’t have the points necessary to do so. How do I do that? I followed you though!  How do I accept as answer?